# using topic exchange to send message from one method to another

Tags: django, message-queue, celery, django-celery, kombu

Recently, I have been going though [celery](http://celeryproject.org) & [kombu](http://kombu.readthedocs.org/) documentation as i need them integrated in one of my projects. I have a basic understanding of how this should work but documentation examples using different brokers have me confused.

Here is the scenario:

Within my application i have two views `ViewA` and `ViewB` both of them does some expensive processing, so i wanted to have them use celery tasks for processing. So this is what i did.

#### views.py

```
def ViewA(request):
    tasks.do_task_a.apply_async(args=[a, b])


def ViewB(request):
    tasks.do_task_b.apply_async(args=[a, b])
```

#### tasks.py

```
@task()
def do_task_a(a, b):
    # Do something Expensive

@task()
def do_task_b(a, b):
    # Do something Expensive here too
```

Until now, everything is working fine. The problem is that `do_task_a` creates a `txt` file on the system, which i need to use in `do_task_b`. Now, in the `do_task_b` method i can check for the file existence and call the tasks `retry` method [which is what i am doing right now] if the file does not exist.

Here, I would rather want to take a different approach (i.e. where messaging comes in). I would want `do_task_a` to send a message to `do_task_b` once the file has been created instead of looping the retry method until the file is created.

I read through the documentation of `celery` and `kombu` and updated my settings as follows.

```
BROKER_URL = "django://"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "sqlite:///celery"
TASK_RETRY_DELAY = 30 #Define Time in Seconds
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['portal.db_routers.CeleryRouter']
CELERY_QUEUES = ( 
    Queue('filecreation', exchange=exchanges.genex, routing_key='file.create'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = ('celeryconf.routers.CeleryTaskRouter',)
```

and i am stuck here.
don't know where to go from here.

What should i do next to make `do_task_a` to broadcast a message to `do_task_b` on file creation ? and what should i do to make `do_task_b` receive (consume) the message and process the code further ??

Any Ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example for using **Celery's callback/linking function**.

Celery supports linking tasks together so that one task follows another.
You can read more about it [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks)

`apply_async()` functions has two optional arguments

```
+link : excute the linked function on success 
+link_error : excute the linked function on an error

@task
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

@task
def total(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)

@task
def error_handler(uuid):
    result = AsyncResult(uuid)
    exc = result.get(propagate=False)
    print('Task %r raised exception: %r\n%r' % (exc, result.traceback))
```

Now in your calling function do something like

```
def main():
    #for error_handling
    add.apply_async((2, 2), link_error=error_handler.subtask())

    #for linking 2 tasks
    add.apply_async((2, 2), link=add.subtask((8, )))
    # output 12

    #what you can do is your case is something like this. 
    if user_requires:
        add.apply_async((2, 2), link=add.subtask((8, )))
    else:
        add.apply_async((2, 2))
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks, i have gone through the linking documentation, but that is not really suitable for my needs. As i need to `do_task_b` on a user request only and not as a subtask of `do_task_a`

Comment: then you can use a chord which is a subtask with a callback method.. use this callback method to run do_task_b based on the users' request

Comment: could you hook me up with an example ?

Comment: @Amyth hope this is helpful.

Comment: I am trying to use callback in my code `send_email.apply_async( args=[json.dumps(payload)], exchange=CELERY_EXCHANGE, routing_key=CELERY_ROUTING_KEY, link=save_email_response.subtask((invite_id, candidate.id, )) )` but it's not calling `save_email_response`. I have verified this using `rdb`